# gigabyte x570 elite aorus not booting up or giving power to peripherals

Tags: troubleshooting, post, build

I build yesterday a system with
aorus elite x570
ryzen 5 3600x
32 gb ram (2x corsair sticks)
Initially it worked fine all day yesterday, installed windows and so on.
Sometimes monitor did not pick up the hdmi signal from graphic card and had to shut down, start pc again.

Anyway today to my surprise system does not boot up !!!
Keyboard does not receive any light (power potentially), fans are working both chasis and cpu fans, but cannot go to bios or receive any video signal

I tried:
remove ram stick, change slots
remove grpahic card, to see if keyboard will receive light at least, still did not help
checked all power cables, atx 12v is set, atx is set (also power is used fine... at least cpu fan chasis fans are spinning ...)
removed all hard drives assuming keyboard might turn on and maybe corrupted windows..., still did not happen no video signal cannot reach bios
How can I troubleshoot the issue and fix it ?Looking forward to some advice as is driving me crazy on my first build -)....

PS: Cannot upload video here but might upload to other site later so you can see the open chasis. Basically motherboard orange light is on, cpu fan is working, chasis fans are working. After some seconds, they stop and restart (barely noticable but mostly from the sound, so seems like infinite restart and never reaches the phase of powering keyboard the devices and bringing signal to hdmi)

I am going crazy as payed a lot of money too.
I don't know how I can tell if problem is in motherboard or cpu died ..., , but mostly what surprised me is that exactly same configuration worked one day before, and pc was not moved physically at all...

Also where can I connect a buzzer to aorus x570 elite, maybe i hear some beep to debug easier... From manual I don't know where I can add buzzer. I connected normal speaker to front audio, also to motherboard audio but hear 0 beep even when pc is "powered up", and fans start to work

Thanks!!!

Comment: No POST beep at start-up ?

Comment: x570 elite oesn't have motherboard speaker, I hear no beep. Also  all lights in back of mobo were on (orange lights), no blinking nothing. They stay on, fans turn on spin a little, then restart spinning an this loop goes on forever